# I want create a measure or table in Power BI that turns all my data as percentual when i put it in a data segmentation

Tags: powerbi, dax, m

In my work, the old analyst created a table that contains two fields:

percent
quantitative

These fields when we put in a data segmentation, all my data turns percent or quantitative, but i don't have any information how he maked it.

I tried create measures that switch the data, but it don't work.
Maybe it's a file imported that makes it.

Answer (score 0):

Share of total is pretty simple.
DIVIDE ( [measure], CALCULATE ( [measure], REMOVEFILTERS('table'[Column]), BLANK() )

[measure] can be any measure that calculates a sum.
the REMOVEFILTERS() is to remove a filter from the evaulation context so that you get an unfiltered total (so for the whole set, for example).

maybe a good book for you might be Rob Collie's book on DAX (the 2nd edition... the first one is crazy old).